# Check Id_token or access_token on identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4

I am using Identityserver4 with my Angular application implicit flow. currently, im facing some Authentication issues and for that i need to verify the token Generated by the IDS and the token i have in my angular client after authentication.

I am not How to get the Token in IdentityServer while authenticating a client ?

here is my oidc related code in angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User, WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client';
import { AppConfigService } from '../../app-config.service';
// import { Config } from '../../../app-config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
private manager;
private user: User = null;

constructor(private appConfig: AppConfigService) {
    this.manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings(appConfig));
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
        this.user = user;
    });
    this.manager.events.addUserLoaded( user => {
        this.user = user;
    });
}
public get UserId() {
    if (this.user && this.user != null && this.user.profile && this.user.profile.sub) {
        return this.user.profile.sub;
    }
    return null;
}
public get User() {
    if (this.user && this.user != null && this.user.profile && this.user.profile != null) {
        return this.user.profile;
    }
    return null;
}
public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
}

public getClaims(): any {
    return this.user.profile;
}

public getAuthorizationHeaderValue(): string {
    //
    return `${this.user.token_type} ${this.user.access_token}`;

}

public startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
}
public signout(): Promise<void> {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    return this.manager.signoutRedirect();
}
public signoutRedirectCallback(): Promise<any> {
    //   localStorage.removeItem('user');
    return this.manager.signoutRedirectCallback();
}

public completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
        this.user = user;
    });
}
public silentRefresh(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('before');
    return this.manager.signinSilentCallback(); // .then(t => console.log(t))
    // .catch((err) => {
    // console.log(err);
    // });
}
public signinSilent(): Promise<User> {
    return this.manager.signinSilent();
}
```

}

```
export function getClientSettings(appConfig: AppConfigService): 
UserManagerSettings {
console.log('in auth service', appConfig.getConfig('IDS_ENDPOINT'));
return {
    authority: appConfig.getConfig('IDS_ENDPOINT'), // 'https://localhost:44360/',
    client_id: appConfig.getConfig('IDS_CLIENT'),
    redirect_uri: appConfig.getConfig('IDS_redirectUrl'), // 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: appConfig.getConfig('IDS_LogoutUrl'), // 'http://localhost:4200/',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid profile roles smsapi country subscriptionlevel permissions',
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60,
    silent_redirect_uri: appConfig.getConfig('IDS_refreshUrl')
   // userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
};
```

}

Any Help?

Comment: Are you using the oidc-client-js library or similar? If so that will implement the implicit flow validation rules as per spec. If not can you explain how you're currently obtaining the tokens?

Comment: yes im using oidc-client-js for my angular app. it works perfectly but there is some scenarion when the application/ Id Server is unable to authenticate the 
 access_token ( referecen type ) in my case. 

so i want to check what token Id server is generating for angular client. and than match the token in angular app in browser.

Comment: It might help if you post the error message you are getting.   at the very least describe the issues and what you are seeing in the logs.

Comment: Okay let me try to explain.

I have ;
    
    1. Authorization Server ( IDS4) (localhost:5000)
    2. Web API (localhost:5001)
    3. Angular App1 (localhost:5002, Angular App2 (localhost:5003)

On Home view of  Authorization Server i have a lins to angular apps.
Now after i am authenticated through localhost:5000 and on home page. when i click on link to go to angular app1 or app2 or any other (i have multiple apps)  

the angular app gets a access_token but the api returns 401 (unauthorized)
but i refresh the page the angular app starts working as normal and api returns data.